# Can't install Ubuntu in VMware

Tags: vmware, ubiquity

I downloaded an Ubuntu iso image file from the official Ubuntu website. I am running VMware in a Windows OS that has not been activated. I tried to install it in VMware but failed. I kept getting an error message that said: `The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk:` and another error message:

```
Problem in ubiquity

This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and  
try again.
```

I am stuck at this. What is this problem about?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would re-download the Ubuntu ISO and try it again. It seems like there is a problem with the files on the ISO disk.

Comment: Especially if the full text of the first error message looks like this screenshot: http://pasteboard.co/2kV8b4Jv.png

Comment: thanx for the suggeston . i am downloading another file right now